# Can we have inputs that is more than 1D in Pytorch (e.g word-embedding)

Tags: neural-network, nlp, pytorch, text-classification

Say I have some text and I want to classify them into three groups `food, sports, science`. If I have a sentence `I dont like to each mushrooms` we can use wordembedding (say 100 dimensions) to create a `6x100` matrix for this particular sentense.

Ususally when training a neural-network our data is a 2D array with the dimensions `n_obs x m_features`

If I want to train a neural network on wordembedded sentences(i'm using Pytorch) then our input is 3D `n_obs x (m_sentences x k_words)`

e.g

```
#Say word-embedding is 3-dimensions
I = [1,2,3]
dont = [4,5,6]
eat = [7,8,9]
mushrooms = [10,11,12]

"I dont eat mushrooms" = [I,dont,eat,mushrooms] #First observation
```

Is the best way, when we have N>2 dimensions, to do some kind of pooling e.g mean, or can we use the actual 2D-features as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the input will be 1D, but that doesn't matter.

The internal architecture of your neural network will take care of recognizing the different words. You could for example have a convolution with a stride equal to the embedding size.

You can flatten a 2D input to become 1D and it will work fine. This is the way you'd normally do it with word embeddings.

```
I = [1,2,3]
dont = [4,5,6]
eat = [7,8,9]
mushrooms = [10,11,12]

input = np.array([I,dont,eat,mushrooms]).flatten()
```

The inputs of a neural network have to always be of the same size, but as sentences are not, you will probably have to limit the the max length of the sentence to a set length of words and add paddings to the end of the shorter sentences:

```
I = [1,2,3]
Am = [4,5,6]
short = [7,8,9]
paddingword = [1,1,1]

input = np.array([I,Am,eat,short, paddingword]).flatten()
```

Also you might want to look at [doc2vec from gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), which is an easy way to make embeddings for texts, which are then easy to use for a text classification problem.

Comment: I thought about flatten as well but then you end up with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,0] (if we zero-pad) e.g now does feature 1 not correspond to word 1, but to the first dimension of the first word. Dont we lose the effect/context of each word then?

Comment: To solve this you can use convolutions with a window and stride size equal to your word embedding size.
Although it's probaby better for you to just use gensin doc2vec

Comment: aaaah of course!! Why didnt I think of that (now I understand what you mean with that suggestion in the answer)